# Error ionic cordova build --release -- --packageType=bundle error javac -version

Tags: ionic, cordova, ionic4, build

Buenas comunidad que tal? resulta que estoy intentando compiar una App con ionic cordova para generar el archivo AAB. no puedo lograrlo bajo ningun circustancia.

El comando que realizo

```
ionic cordova build android --release -- --packageType=bundle

CordovaError: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
```

Ahora este es el error principal. Tambien tuve errores con las versiones que ya instale.
este es mi **java --version**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

pero en javac -v

```
zsh: command not found: javac
```

tuve que instalar la version 8 del JDK ya que es lo que me pide android studio, o en realidad, el proyecto esta hecho en esta version y tuve que acomodarme a ella.
Tengo instalado Android Studio, Android SDK.

No se por donde empezar a tocar. Algunas de las dudas que me surgen:

**como agregar javac??**

**debo agregar javac o cambiar alguna variable?** => cambie variables de JAVA_HOME y (etc/environment) y se me daño el inicio de ubuntu.

**donde se agregan las varibales de entorno en ubuntu?**

**como se agregan las variables para que no se borren en ubuntu?=**> estuve creando varibales, siguiendo dif documentaciones, la de cordova me dice que la haga en ~/.bash_profile... cuando quiero ver esa variable creada con `export` no aparece nada.

Bueno si alguien paso por este calvario, y sabe alguna solucion le agreadeceria. Por ultimo dejo mi ionic info para que vean. GRACIAS!!!

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.11.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.4
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 24 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v14.19.1 (/home/userX/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.16
   OS     : Linux 5.13
```

**gracias nuevamente**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre el problema. Muy tonto ciertamente.

me faltaba instalar el paquete JRE de java.(v8)

y el export fue el siguiente

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-open-jdk8-amd64